# Takes one of the values from the data loop according to its value

Tags: php, jquery

I have my data show with arrays, but I have a problem when I want to click on one of the data that appear all the same, must be different, what is wrong with my script

```
<?php 
    foreach($data as $row){
?>  
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="set_module">         
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="post-module">
            <div class="tmb">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/file/image-module/<?php echo $row->image; ?>"/>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="id_m[<?php echo $row->id_module;?>]" id="id_m" value="<?php echo $row->id_module;?>"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
    </a>
 <?php } ?>
```

This my jquery

```
$("a.set_module").on("click",  function (event) {
   event.preventDefault(); 
    var value = $('#id_m').val();
    alert(value);
    return false;
});
```

the example above is I have data A, B, C and I show it by looping but when I click one of the data only data A keep appearing

Comment: Looks like you're duplicating IDs, and they **must** be unique.

Comment: ^^ this should be posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this
change id to class in this line

```
<input type="text" name="id_m[<?php echo $row->id_module;?>]" class="id_m" value="<?php echo $row->id_module;?>"></input>
```

and then in js

```
$("a.set_module").on("click",  function (event) {
event.preventDefault(); 
var value = $(this).find('.id_m').val();
alert(value);
return false;
});
```

fidle example
http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KVC/3543/

Answer (score 0):

use css class insted of id. and find that class with $(this). 
or use dynamic id like  `id="id_m<?php echo $row->id_module;?>"` and change this  `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="set_module">`      with `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="set_module" data-uid="<?php echo $row->id_module;?>">`
. after that change the script

as follows

```
$("a.set_module").on("click",  function (event) { event.preventDefault(); var uid = $(this).data('uid'); var value = $('#id_m'+uid).val();  alert(value); return false;});
```